# How do I change the FOV (field of view) in The Darkness II?

Tags: pc, the-darkness-2

By default, The Darkness II seems to use a very narrow field of view, which I am not particularly fond of.

Is there an option of any kind – be it in-game, command line, INI file, or whatever – to change the FOV?

Comment: Related: http://www.complex.com/video-games/2012/02/the-darkness-2-dev-working-on-adding-field-of-view-options-for-pc-gamers

Answer (score 2):

According to [2kElizabeth](http://forums.2kgames.com/member.php?2-2K-Elizabeth) (Sr. Manager, Interactive Marketing, 2K Games) field of view is currently fixed, listed [here](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?117407-Anti-Aliasing-and-FOV&p=1503312#post1503312). From some of the back and forth about it the devs are [working on fixing it](https://twitter.com/#!/sheldoncarter/status/167409595625639937). If you want you can also check a video that was made today about the issue [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DPDq_qvsKUA&feature=plcp&context=C3325da8UDOEgsToPDskL4CvpYksv88r56K3AJV9nh).

As to your question about if something can be done, on the forums some people are trying to get it to work, might be the best place to find something.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it using a third party utility, [Widescreen Fixer](http://www.widescreenfixer.org).  Choose "The Darkness 2" from the list of games, and set the FOV you want to use.